# Monitor Chat REST API Error

Tags: rest-api, liveagent, einstein-chatbot

So in our chatbot application we are using the following API to connect with the live agents -- [Rest API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_Messages.htm)

While using the Messages API which is https://hostname/chat/rest/System/Messages, sometimes we are getting 403 session is either invalid or not found error if the user is still in a queue (We have gotten the ChatRequestSuccess event but not the ChatEstablished one)

I have verified that we are sending the correct parameters even in the case when the API is failing.

We are calling this API back to back as is required.

So is there any sort of timeout linked to the sessions that are generated or in what cases can this API lead to this sort of error since from our end we are sending the same data everytime.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @SubratSrivastava

The API just responds with a 403 status code with the message either the session is invalid or doesnt exist